# Creating a function in DB2 on IBM,ZOS(failed with THE CLAUSES ARE MUTUALLY EXCLUSIVE)

Tags: function, db2

I would like to create and deploy this function in DB2, but I got stuck. Could you please help me?

Cheers,

My function  code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getID(NameIn VARCHAR(255),versionIn varchar(255))
 RETURNS varchar(12)
 NOT DETERMINISTIC
 LANGUAGE SQL
 MODIFIES SQL DATA
 NO EXTERNAL ACTION
 BEGIN 
  declare IDOut varchar(12);
  set IDOut = (select mID 
    from mIDHolder 
    where mName = NameIn and version = versionIn);
  IF mappingIDOut IS NULL THEN
    set IDOut = Hex(GENERATE_UNIQUE());
    insert into mIDHolder VALUES (IDOut,NameIn,versionIn);
  END IF;
  RETURN IDOut;
 END
```

Here is the mIDHolder Table DDL

```
CREATE TABLE "V"."MIDHOLDER" (
    "MID" VARCHAR(12) FOR SBCS DATA NOT NULL, 
    "MNAME" VARCHAR(255) FOR SBCS DATA WITH DEFAULT NULL, 
    "VERSION" VARCHAR(255) FOR SBCS DATA WITH DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Comment: the function is not deploying, it fails with error (THE CLAUSES ARE MUTUALLY EXCLUSIVE))

Comment: Is all your code here? Because from the doc (http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc.codes%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fn628.htm) I don't see what is causing the error.

Comment: it is all here, I read that documnet already, that's the reason I got stuck, if you have access to a DB2 system you can check it and see the error :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of DB2 for zOS are you using?

Looking at [the documentation for CREATE FUNCTION](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_createfunctionsqlscalar.htm) on version 10, it states that `MODIFIES SQL DATA` is incompatible with `ALLOW PARALLEL`.  And `ALLOW PARALLEL` is the default when you specify `NO EXTERNAL ACTION`. I suspect this is your problem.

On the other hand, looking at the [documentation for CREATE FUNCTION](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_createproceduresqlexternal.htm) on version 9.1, I don't see `MODIFIES SQL DATA` mentioned as an option anywhere.  In fact, if you look at what they say under `READS SQL DATA` it strongly suggests that statements that modify tables are not allowed in functions at all.

In my experience, function and procedure definitions are terribly finicky, error messages are opaque, and there are big differences between DB2 versions.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing this, I see. So I need to solve my problem in an other way :(, So let me ask you another question then, (in next comment)

Comment: @happyNewLife, did you see my edit?  If you are using version 10 I think you could solve it just by adding `DISALLOW PARALLEL`.

Comment: I think we have version 8 :( , I added the DISALLOW PARALLEL, but it is not deployable

Comment: @happyNewLife, do you need to use this function within a query?  If not, you can probably get around the limitations of functions by using a procedure instead.

Comment: I wanted to use it in a view, so now I need to solve my problem in other way. I was going to use a view to convert ROW data into columns format. Let's assume the following link is my data and forget about the above question at the moment. [LINK TO e.g](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/40ecc108-18de-45cb-a25a-d243f59b44e2/). Assume that (sector and baseCharge) are repeated in the rows. I wanted to give this both combination a unique ID in a view. Therefore I've though a function can sole the problem. Do you have any other suggestion?creating a unique ID for ea

Comment: @happyNewLife, I think there are many potential solutions.  However, this is different enough that I think you should post it as a new question.  Include the example data directly in the question, and also explain clearly why you need this unique ID (what you want to use it for)